# Is there a good machine-readable thesaurus?

Tags: thesaurus

Is there a good machine-readable thesaurus that's free to download and use?  We need to be able to canonicalise input into our app so that if we already have a record for 'what time is dinner' and the user adds 'when is dinner' we don't get a new record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) includes a thesaurus library called MyThes. You can use that (or just the data files if you want to roll your own). If you're using .NET you can use [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/) which is the same as Hunspell but for .NET. You should be able to get some good use out of that.

Comment: but this is written in C++. what about to offer one for Java programmers?